# Does HTML video tag work on grails?

Tags: html, grails, html5-video

So I want to put a video that I downloaded into my grails web app. So far I've been trying to use the usual html video tag and it does not work and the flashplayer plugin gives me error. Any suggestion?
Note: Grails ver 2.4.4

Comment: please see this link http://www.tothenew.com/blog/using-custom-tag-for-embedding-the-video-in-grails/

Answer (score 0):

> Does HTML video tag work on grails?

Yes.  You can embed any markup you like in a GSP.  Grails doesn't interfere with that and it is up to your browser to interpret the markup.